# Commandline complete list of commands

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

Is there a way/command to get a listing of all the commands available on my system from the commandline prompt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> once or twice will display a message such as:

```
Display all 435 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> will display all commands you can run that are on your default path.

Comment: I get 'Display all 2821 possibilities?' I'm not sure I want to see them all. *But if I do, they're paged with* `more`

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to pipe this output to `less` instead of `more`? (mine is 4481 long :P) If you can, you could then search within the list by typing `/keyword`

Comment: I think you can set the environment variable `PAGER` to `/usr/bin/less` (or whatever the full path to `less` is), and then bash will use `less` for paging.

Comment: Pressing Y did nothing. Double tab did work, thanks!

Comment: I figured out that pressing the esc key twice shows that same results as pressing the tab key.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to display all commands available in your *$PATH*, you may use this command:

```
ls $(echo $PATH | tr ":" " ")
```

If you want to display all executable files available on your filesystem, you may use this command (beware, it might take some time):

```
find / -type f \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \) 2>/dev/null
```

The files listed by this command are not necessarily commands, they are just set as executable.

(you might need to run it as root if you want to search, remove the *2> /dev/null* part to know where the *find* command did not search as a normal user)

You may also want to list your aliases, to do so , you can use this command:

```
alias
```

Comment: The first command would be better written like this: `ls ${PATH//:/ }|sort -u`

Answer (score 7):

In **bash**, you can use `compgen -c` to get all command completions generated to stdout (so you can use `grep`, etc. instead of just paging through the list). You can also add a prefix:

```
$ compgen -c ls
ls
lsbom
lsbom
lsdiff
lsof
lsvfs
lsvfs

$ compgen -c | grep zcat
bzcat
bzcat
bzcat
gzcat
gzcat
lzcat
zcat
zcat

$ compgen -c | sort -u | grep zcat
bzcat
gzcat
lzcat
zcat
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but you could either `ls /usr/bin` or `ls /usr/sbin` or list all the mans `ls /usr/share/man/man1`

Answer (score 1):

On a slightly different note:

Many linux systems have `man` installed.

`man -k searchword` will list all commands (which have manual files) which have `searchword` in their description, a little more in-depth and comprehensive (`man cmdname` will then list the manual for `cmdname`).

Answer (score 0):

All the products installed in your system can be executed from the command-line.

However, some built-in commands are available that are specific to the shell that you use.

Here are pointers to documentation about some most used shells : [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash), [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) (sh), [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) (csh).

For some shells the built-in `help` command displays helpful information about the built-in commands.