# Where does the information shown by OS X Terminal 'Display all commands' feature come from?

Tags: bash

I just learned that if you hit and hold <kbd>ESC</kbd> while on the Mac Terminal, a prompt appears after a few seconds offering to show every command available on your system, including aliases, built-ins, and executables on your PATH.

Soruce: http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/05/list-all-possible-terminal-commands.html

However, the output is show through a `more` filter, and I cannot `grep` it or pipe it to another command.

Does anyone know how this magic output is generated? Is it just generated on the fly by Terminal? Is there a bash command that can be called explicitly on the command line and get the same result?

It is mostly curiosity, but I would love to be able to get the results as text I can post-process and not just browse on screen.

Comment: Retagged because it's a bash feature.

Comment: Great, thanks. That's a start: at least now I know it is not Terminal.app but bash the one who does the trick.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/58201/commandline-complete-list-of-commands

Comment: Just press Esc twice at an empty prompt - no need to hold it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams commented, this functionality comes from the *bash* completion feature. The *compgen* built-in command provides access to the functionality.

You can access the command completion like this:

```
# all commands
compgen -c
# command starting with "ls"
compgen -c ls
```